# Javascript pages within a page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a 'Next/Previous' system within a page - where it shows one specific item, or 'page', at a time. I can't seem to find a practical solution online. It's currently working, but the code is unprofessional and needlessly long/complicated especially when I want it to have up to 5 pages.

I'm not an experienced JS programmer so please go easy on me!

HTML -

```
<div id="page1">Page 1 <button onclick="secondPage()">Next</button></div>
<div id="page2">Page 2 <button onclick="thirdPage()">Next</button></div>
<div id="page3">Page 3 <button onclick="fourthPage()">Next</button></div>
<div id="page4">Page 4</div>
```

CSS -

```
.hidden {
display:none;
}
```

JS -

```
        function secondPage() {
            document.getElementById("page1").classList.add('hidden');
            document.getElementById("page2").classList.remove('hidden');
            document.getElementById("page3").classList.add('hidden');
            document.getElementById("page4").classList.add('hidden');
        }
        function thirdPage() {
            document.getElementById("page1").classList.add('hidden');
            document.getElementById("page2").classList.add('hidden');
            document.getElementById("page3").classList.remove('hidden');
            document.getElementById("page4").classList.add('hidden');
        }
        function fourthPage() {
            document.getElementById("page1").classList.add('hidden');
            document.getElementById("page2").classList.add('hidden');
            document.getElementById("page3").classList.add('hidden');
            document.getElementById("page4").classList.remove('hidden');
        }
```

If anyone is able to help me simplify this bit of code with a cleaner and better script that would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use traditional links vs javascript navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic implementation would likely be to store a global variable that keeps track of which page number is currently visible.

Using that number you could fetch the Ids dynamically, e.g. `` `page${currentPageNumber}` `` would result in something like `page2`.

Similarly, you could get the *next* page by doing `` `page${currentPageNumber+1}` ``.

```js
let currentPageNumber = 1;
function nextPage() {
  document.getElementById(`page${currentPageNumber}`).classList.add("hidden");        //Hide the current page
  document.getElementById(`page${currentPageNumber+1}`).classList.remove("hidden");   //Show the next page
  currentPageNumber++;                                                                //Increase currentPage accordingly
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="page1">Page 1 <button onclick="nextPage()">Next</button></div>
<div id="page2" class="hidden">Page 2 <button onclick="nextPage()">Next</button></div>
<div id="page3" class="hidden">Page 3 <button onclick="nextPage()">Next</button></div>
<div id="page4" class="hidden">Page 4</div>
```